# Why the SOAP server returns no values as they are specified in the function server

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, soapserver

I have a function on the SOAP server that returns a two dimensional array

example (A function which returns an associative array where one field is a two-dimensional array):

```
function example_function($id_array){

    $res = array("errors" => false, "message" => "ok message", "2_array" => array(array("asd" => 1, "sdf" => 2), array("asd" => 3, "sdf" => 5)));

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($res);
    echo "</pre>";

    return $res;

}
```

If you run this function directly, turning to the server, we get a well structured answer that I need

```
array(3) {
  ["errors"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["message"]=>
  string(10) "ok message"
  ["2_array"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["asd"]=>
      int(1)
      ["sdf"]=>
      int(2)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["asd"]=>
      int(3)
      ["sdf"]=>
      int(5)
    }
  }
}
```

But, if we run this function from the SoapClient, we get the following output:

```
$opts = array(
     'http' => array(
         'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
     )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClientOptions = array(
    'stream_context' => $context,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
);
$client = new SoapClient("http://some_address/wsdl.wsdl", $soapClientOptions);
$result = $client->example_function();

var_dump($result);
```

return:

```
object(stdClass)#195 (3) {
  ["errors"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["message"]=>
  string(23) "ok message"
  ["2_array"]=>
  object(stdClass)#196 (1) {  //I don't know why is stdClass
    ["Map"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#202 (1) { //I dont't know why "item"
        ["item"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#203 (2) {
            ["key"]=>
            string(3) "asd"
            ["value"]=>
            string(1) "1"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#204 (2) {
            ["key"]=>
            string(3) "sdf"
            ["value"]=>
            string(1) "2"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#205 (1) {
        ["item"]=>
        array(2) {
          //similarly
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the error?

Comment: What's in your WSDL?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174979/returning-a-php-array-from-a-php-soapserver